# How do I add data to particular column in exisiting table?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How can I insert data to only one column in an existing table?

I dont want other column get disturbed or altered..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for an update query:

```
UPDATE
  table_name
SET
  column = 'value';
```

That will only "insert" data into a single column while leaving everything else undisturbed.

If you want to update from the results of another table, you can also do joins:

```
UPDATE
  table_name
    INNER JOIN source_table ON
      table_name.some_id = source_table.some_id
SET
  table_name.column = source_table.column;
```

Hope that helps.  You might want to try clarifying the question with some more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "insert" as in "update" then

```
# to a fixed value
update tbl set col = "abc"
# WHERE <some condition>  # optionally identify which record

# add to existing value
update tbl set col = concat(col, "abc")   # add "abc" to the end of the current value
# WHERE <some condition>  # optionally identify which record
```